# How to test if randomization influenced the results?

Tags: distributions, crossover-study

I did an experiment where one group of participants answered questions using an existing tool and the other group my tool, which has some additional features. Everyone received 2 tasks, one complex and one simple and then they answered questions regarding the task. They received tasks in an random order, i.e. one participant received complex task first and answered questions regarding the complex task first as well, and then they did the same for the simple task. Another participant received simple task first and then the complex. Now, when i have the results, i joined answers regarding the complex tasks and simple tasks. Now I'm wondering: how do i test if the randomization (simple or complex task first) influenced the results??? The data is not normally distributed.

Comment: What is your sample size of the group; this could explain why the data doesn't look normally distributed? Might be a good candidate for a t-test. Sounds like you have two groups. First group got the complex task first, 2nd group simple task first. Split the data into those groups then perform a similar operation to this R `t.test(group1$answer_avg, group2$answer_avg)` I am interested in how others see it.

Comment: I used nonparametric tests, the group sizes are 43 and 41. I only worry that the randomization of tasks (simple or complex first) could influence the results? How do I test that this didn't influence the results?

Comment: Matt L. I actually have four groups: one used my tool and got complex task first, the second used my tool and got simple task first, third got existing tool and complex task first and forth group got existing tool and simple task first. Actually, i want to represent the data as two groups: one that used existing tool and the other that used my tool. However, can i just join complex answers together and simple ones together? Did the randomization of tasks have an influence? How to test that?